# Why Multiply operator does not work with BigInteger?

Tags: groovy, operators

Can someone explain why the multiply operator throws an `IllegalAccessException` exception whereas all other operators works as expected?

```
BigInteger plus = 10000000000000000000 + 100 // 10000000000000000100
BigInteger minus = 10000000000000000000 - 100 // 9999999999999999900
BigInteger div = 10000000000000000000 / 100 // 100000000000000000
BigInteger mod = 10000000000000000000 % 100 // 0
BigInteger pow = 10000000000000000000 ** 2 // 100000000000000000000000000000000000000
BigInteger star = 10000000000000000000 * 100 // java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on java.math.BigInteger java.math.BigInteger.multiply(long)
```

- Groovy version: *2.4.4*
- Java Version: *1.7.0*

Comment: What is the Groovy version you use? This exception does not occur in Groovy 2.4.12

Comment: And what Java version?

Comment: This works fine in Groovy 2.4.5 with Java 1.8.0_152

Answer (score 0):

It's true that this does not happen on Groovy 2.4.later (I'm trying on .13 for example).  In Groovy 2.4.4 and probably earlier, this works as you would expect:

```
new BigInteger("10000000000000000000") * new BigInteger("100")
```

However, there are still overflow risks even in 2.4.13.  Consider:

```
BigInteger b = 100000000 * 100
println b
// outputs 1410065408 because the multiplication of ints happens first, overflows, and the result is converted to BigInteger
```

While Groovy can convert int to BigInteger by default, mathematical operations can (and maybe should?  I did not find clear guidance either way) happen first.  In your example I'd guess the first is being converted and the second is not, and that is exposing some bug that has since been fixed.